# How to get value of other selectmenu()?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery ui selectmenu().

I already gone through https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

I have 2 select box.  I want to use 1st selectbox value in second. So how can i get value of 1st selectbox.

For temporary i'm doing this.

```
 <select class="select" id="one">
     <option value="1">A</option>
     <option value="2">B</option>    
 </select>

 <select class="select2">
     <option value="1">A</option>
     <option value="2">B</option>    
 </select>

 $(".select").selectmenu();
    $(".select2").selectmenu({
        change: function (event, data) {

            var firstVal = $("#one-button .ui-selectmenu-text").text();
            alert(firstVal);
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Is there better way to get value of first selectbox?

It's generating below kind of HTML

```
<span class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" id="one-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="continents_1-menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 0px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-29" aria-labelledby="ui-id-29" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-text">1</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Value is "1", label is "A". So what do you need?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2pza5/

Comment: Hi dfsq, var firstVal = $("#one-button .ui-selectmenu-text").text(); this is temporary solution i have done. So using selectmenu API's one of the option can i get this?

Comment: Sometime it happens, we know basics (how to get select value), but we choose harder ways. Don't know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the value of the select element, the selectui updates the value of the underlying select element.

```
var firstVal = $("#one").val();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ds5vp6ks/)

Comment: @Jack have a look at the attached fiddle... in is printing the selected value... look at the console to see the logged values

Comment: How to get selected value out of change function?

Answer (score 2):

Since UI selectmenu is basically just a HTML wrapper around plain select box which mirrors its values and labels, you can still read values and labels normally. In your case:

```
var firstVal = $("#one").find(':selected').text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6uxh7znb/

Answer (score 0):

Below code sample will get the value from first select box and will set it as value in the second select box

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".select").change(function() {
    //this will give you value of first select box
    var selectedval = ($(".select option:selected").val());
    //this will set the value from first select box in second select box
    $(".select2").val(selectedval);
    });
    });
```